# JSON parsing not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a text field with id `search_json` on a form that contains:

```
{"standard_id":"2","attribute1":["","Stan"],"attribute2":[""],"attribute3":["","Air Force"],"attribute4":["","Bob"],"selected_index":3}
```

Upon some event, call it a button click, I want to:

1) Read in that JSON and parse it into an object:

```
search_json = $.parseJSON($("#search_json").val())
```

2) Remove "attribute1" from the object

```
delete search_json["attribute1"]
```

3) Write the JSON back out to the text field:

```
$("#search_json").val(JSON.stringify(search_json))
```

I'm kind of surprised it's not working, though. The `delete` call does nothing. As a matter of fact,

```
search_json.hasOwnProperty("attribute1")
```

returns `false`. And yet I can log the object to console and it is indeed an object with those values. What is going wrong here?

UPDATE: Actually,

```
search_json.hasOwnProperty("attribute1")
```

DOES work. But, if I get the attribute name from another text field, like so:

```
attribute_name = $("#attribute_name").attr("id")
```

and:

```
console.log attribute_name
```

shows "attribute1", then this does NOT work:

```
search_json.hasOwnProperty(attribute_name)
```

returns FALSE. Mystifying.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: *shrugh* http://jsfiddle.net/ddQbe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it. I'm using your fiddle code and everything is correct

http://jsfiddle.net/ddQbe/1/

The final object is:

```
attribute2: Array[1]
attribute3: Array[2]
attribute4: Array[2]
selected_index: 3
standard_id: "2"
```

attribute1 was delete correclty

Answer (score 1):

I would try creating a new result_json object.

```
var result_json = {};
for (var prop in search_json) {
    if (prop !== 'attribute1') {
        result_json[prop] = search_json[prop];
    }
}
$("#search_json").val(JSON.stringify(result_json));
```